# Android runtime fatal exception

Tags: java, android, google-maps, sdk, fatal-error

My app that uses Google Maps SDK just started crashing with this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                         
Process: com.example.newspaperdelivery, PID: 29598
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newspaperdelivery/com.example.newspaperdelivery.DeliveryMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  
    You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     
    meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:8)                                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)                                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzca.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:3)                                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:4)                                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)                                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzav.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:2)                                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzav.createDelegate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)                                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:6)                                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)                                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:9)                                                                                                            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1731)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:103)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.example.newspaperdelivery.databinding.ActivityDeliveryMapBinding.inflate(ActivityDeliveryMapBinding.java:36)
    at com.example.newspaperdelivery.databinding.ActivityDeliveryMapBinding.inflate(ActivityDeliveryMapBinding.java:30)
    at com.example.newspaperdelivery.DeliveryMapActivity.onCreate(DeliveryMapActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
2023-06-09 12:11:26.705 29598-29598 AndroidRuntime          com.example.newspaperdelivery        E      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
$